# Check if a date is between two other dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Model called "Tenant" and it has two Date attributes `tenant_from` and `tenant_until`.

I want to write a method that checks if `Date.today` is between the two dates I mentioned above. I want to do something along these lines:

```
IF Date.today IS BETWEEN tenant.tenant_from AND tenant.tenant_until DO
  ...
ELSE
  ...
```

Answer (score 28):

Try

```
if Time.zone.today.between?(tenant.tenant_from, tenant.tenant_until)
  # YOUR CODE GOES HERE
else
  # YOUR CODE GOES HERE
end
```

Answer (score 13):

Just for an alternate solution. You can use a Date range and `cover?` to achieve the same effect.

```
(tenant.tenant_from .. tenant.tenant_until).cover?(Date.today)
```

Comment: I'd recommend wrapping `..` in spaces for readability. White space helps our eyes pick out parts of strings, code, etc., which enhances maintainability.

Answer (score 2):

```
Class Tenant < ActiveRecord::Base
  def current? #name this what you want, but keep the question mark, since it returns a boolean
    (tenant.tenant_from.to_date .. tenant.tenant_until.to_date).include?(Date.today)
  end
end
```

Now you have model logic on an instance of the model (where it belongs). Your logic is then `if @tenant.current?`.

Comment: Mallanaga has a great point! Hide "business logic" like this in your model. It seems like a minor thing, but over time it really helps your views and controllers stay readable, lean and clutter free!